# How can I update my react build folder after deployment without rebuilding

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app that is to be deployed on a static server but then I have this issue. How can I **constantly watch for changes** in **production/build folder without having to rebuild the whole application** with **npm run build** every time I make changes. It's annoying. I have come across this similar issue on GitHub but for **watching changes in development** https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1070. I still did not get the workaround. Am generally new to reactjs.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you followed the https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#quick-overview? I'd use `npm start` in development, and then `npm build` when you're ready to update the live site - this is probably best do using a Continous Integration/Continuous Deployment server/service, that does stuff like run tests and minifies everything.

Comment: This is what I get with npm run build. ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir ' unless there is another error in my build folder.

Comment: Use `react-hot-loader` in development. In production, you should rebuild when changes are made.

Comment: The rebuiding is my issue @JaredGogue. A times it works but in most case getting this error **Failed to compile.

ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\git\peter\tax-api\taxsolutions\build\static' ** so am forced to get rid of it and build a completely new one which is annoying. **npm run build** either takes too long to note changes

Comment: I would think that some other process is locking the files that webpack is trying to change

Answer (score 0):

You definitely **should not** watch for changes in your `build` folder.

Probably you are using `Webpack`. It is designed to wrap up all your code stuff into *a static bundle* that can be served on a production server.

Comment: In order to make changes to my build folder, I have to get rid of it first for changes to take effect coz this what am getting with npm run build. **ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\git\peter\tax-api\taxsolutions\build\static'**. Yeah am using webpack.